# Clean Ubuntu Install from Mint

Tags: system-installation

New to Linux. Mint and I don't mix. I want to switch from Mint to Ubuntu. I have no files to save.  How can i accomplish total, clean, complete Ubuntu install (No home folder creation. No dual anything. No partitions to save anything.)? Do I actually have to "uninstall" the Mint OS?  I cannot find anything anywhere that explains how to do this. What key do I press during start-up to let me change boot order to the bootable Ubuntu USB?

Comment: No you don't need to uninstall Linux Mint. Boot your Ubuntu install media & install.  With no files to save, I'd just format over the Mint so nothing from its setup could leave issues for Ubuntu (even thoughts it is a very small risk).

Comment: Thank you, guiverc. Exactly what I want to do. The problem is that I keep pressing the Esc key when Mint is booting up, I'm not presented with the screen for changing the boot order.  (If it helps, I'm using 32bit. on 2010 HP laptop)

Comment: Are you using a wireless keyboard?  You may find it easier to temporarily connect a wired keyboard, or you could try F10 to enter bios and maybe something there will help (sorry I don't know)

Comment: ... or F9 or F12 (there are different hotkeys in different computers) ...

Comment: guiverc: No wireless keyboard.  It's an old HP Mini laptop that was running  Windows 7Startup 32bit.  Impressed with the new life Mint gave to it, but wanting to experience Ubuntu b4 installing on primary devices.